# Error in Regular expression for find File according a Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to develop this pattern in regular expression:

Pattern:

> 201410021600(12 Numbers)-Only two options A or B_(ZZ always
>   same)616048(6 numbers)_BBBB(4 characters)-123456ABCDEF(12
>   alfanumeric)_OUT(always same).pdf(always same)

Real example:

> 201410021600-A_ZZ123456_BBBB-123456ABCDEF_OUT.pdf.

This is my attempt, but didn,t work :(:

```
\d{12}-{1}A_{1}\bZZ\b\d{6}_{1}\d{4}-{1}\w{12}_{1}\bOUT.pdf\b
```

Somebody can help me, please?

Comment: \d{12}-{1}A_{1}\bZZ\b\d{6}{1}\d{4}-{1}\w{12}_{1}\bOUT.pdf\b

Comment: What do you mean by this `BBBB(4 characters)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify a quantity for 1, i.e. instead of `-{1}` or `_{1}` just `-` or `_` are sufficient.

Additionally, you're specifying the quantity twice here: `\d{6}{1}` which is not necessary.

Third, `\b` marks a word boundary which means there needs to be at least some whitespace. Thus `\bZZ\b` won't match your input.

Applying all this, your regex looks like this and should work: `\d{12}-[AB]_ZZ\d{6}_[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}_OUT\.pdf`

To break it down:

- `201410021600(12 Numbers)` -> `\d{12}`
- `-Only two options A or B` -> `-[AB]` **UPDATE**: from your comment it seems as if `A` and `B` are words and not just characters, so you can't use a character class here but need to use a group instead, e.g. `-(?>A|B)` (`(?>...)` means the group is non-capturing, i.e. you can't retrieve it using `Matcher.group(x)` etc.)
- `_(ZZ always same)` -> `_ZZ`
- `616048(6 numbers)`-> `\d{6}`
- `_BBBB(4 characters)` -> `_[A-Z]{4}` (I assume only upper case chars are allowed)
- `-123456ABCDEF(12 alfanumeric)` -> `-[A-Z0-9]{12}` (in case only upper case characters are allowed)
- `_OUT(always same)` - > `_OUT`
- `.pdf(always same)` -> `\.pdf` (the dot matches any character so it needs to be escaped)

If case is not a matter, i.e. if `201410021600-a_zz123456_bbbb-123456abcdef_out.pdf.` should match as well, then either add `a-z` to the character classes that should allow lower case (e.g. `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[A-Z]`) or add `(?i)` at the front of the expression if lower case is always allowed.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! -Only two options A or B -> -[AB], I have to change that for words like ON or OFF I triyed with [ON | OFF] but didn't work :( where is the error?

Comment: @JOANA_Batista `[...]` is a character class, so that cannot be used for larger matches. Change that to `(?>ON|OFF)` to define those options in a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
Pattern p =Pattern.compile("\\d{12}-[AB]_ZZ\\d{6}_\\w{4}-\\w{12}_OUT.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{12}-[AB]_ZZ\d{6}_[a-zA-Z]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}_OUT\.pdf$
```

Try this.Validates all your rules.

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/19